# Keep a history of Clicktools survey responses

Tags: json, history-tracking, data-model, clicktools

### The Use Case

Part of our operation is collecting survey data from our Accounts.  We currently do this using Clicktools.

Our users would like to track the responses these Accounts give over time.  This would be easy, but sometimes the survey changes.

### My Possible Solutions

#### Easy solution dismissed

It's easy to create a SurveyResponse object tied to the Account record.  It's also easy to map Clicktools to this object, and to include a hidden field with the survey version on it.

What is harder is to maintain historical data when the survey drastically changes and I don't want to maintain extraneous fields in the database.

#### A better plan?

My plan was to generate a YAML or JSON file each time a SurveyResponse is created and attach it to the SurveyResponse as a document.  That way, it is machine-readable and human-readable, and even if our data structure changes, we can tell what folks entered.

### The Question

Is there a better way?  This seems a bit overly complex.

If this is a decent approach, what tools should I use to let the user view the surveys?  I guess a Javascript tool that deserializes a list of JSON objects into a table might be a good way forward.

Has anyone done this sort of thing in the past?

Comment: As a meta-question, if anyone wants to retag this, I'd appreciate it.  Not sure within which tags this falls.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience of doing a similar implementation. We had a field called Survey Name(Dropdown) which was more of an indicator of the Survey version. For each Survey you can have a different set of question and answers. But instead of creating the Survey Question and Answer as fields on the Response Object , you can create Question-1, Answer-1 ; Question-2; Answer-2. This way you can maintain the question and answers in the same object though it could be different for different versions.

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Ansuman